# Strange behaviour when manually converting java.sql.Timestamp to LocalDate

Tags: java, datetime, timestamp

I built a small function to convert a TimeStamp into a LocalDate, and stumbled upon strange behaviour. Here is the code:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Test {

  private static void convert(long seconds) {
    System.out.printf("At %d seconds%n", seconds);
    Timestamp t = new Timestamp(seconds * 1000L);
    System.out.format("Timestamp: %s%n", t);
    Instant i = t.toInstant();
    System.out.format("Instant:   %s%n", i);
    ZonedDateTime atZone = i.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    System.out.format("at Zone:   %s%n", atZone);
    LocalDate localDate = atZone.toLocalDate();
    System.out.format("LocalDate: %s%n", localDate);
  }
}
```

My local timezone is Europe/Berlin.
Now, when calling this for Timestamp 0, I get the correct result:

```
At 0 seconds
Timestamp: 1970-01-01 01:00:00.0
Instant:   1970-01-01T00:00:00Z
at Zone:   1970-01-01T01:00+01:00[Europe/Berlin]
LocalDate: 1970-01-01
```

Everything is as expected.
But when I call it with a date in the year 1, it fails my expectations:

```
At -62135769600 seconds
Timestamp: 0001-01-01 01:00:00.0
Instant:   0000-12-30T00:00:00Z
at Zone:   0000-12-30T00:53:28+00:53:28[Europe/Berlin]
LocalDate: 0000-12-30
```

**Questions:**

1. There is a missing day after converting to Instant, so it seems like the timezones UTC and Europe/Berlin were a day plus one hour apart at that time?
2. When converting the Instant back to my timezone, 6 minutes and 32 seconds get lost somewhere! Why is that?
3. The resulting LocalDate is not correct. What would be a robust way to do the conversion?

Comment: Just out of interest: What are you trying to calculate so close After Christ? As statetd [in the JavaDocs of `java.sql.Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html), it is *a thin wrapper around `java.util.Date`* but also that *it is recommended that code not view Timestamp values generically as an instance of `java.util.Date`*. Best practice: Don't use anything related to `java.util.Date` for calculations on dates and times anymore. [This](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) tells you why...

Comment: @deHaar: I am trying to connect to a legacy backend, which, in the case it wants to return a  NULL date returns `0001-01-01`as a timestamp instead, and I want to write a converter to LocalDate that would handle that case and return NULL.

Comment: Couldn't you then just perform checks for `LocalDate.getYear() > 1` or similar? I mean always convert the timestamp and check the resulting `LocalDate` for valid values.

Comment: Sure, many workarounds are possible, I just want to understand what's happening! :)

Comment: Well, me too ;-) I have checked if the year 0 is considered a leap year, and it seems like it is... Could be (one of) the reason(s) for a weird amount of seconds to be subtracted... I think `java.time` is not perfectly designed for dates and times around Christ. In addition, there shouldn't be a year 0, but only a year 1 B.C. immediately followed by a year 1 A.C... Not entirely sure about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've encountered this issue with I tried to switch from XMLGregorianCalendar over to java.time.ZonedDateTime and our system depended on Year 1 to represent a 'minimum' date. Things get very weird once you start converting between dates before the Julian-Gregorian transition.
e.g.
[image: Year 201]
[image: Year 200]

Here's the Javadoc snippet that hints at things going a bit funny in the early years

> GregorianCalendar implements proleptic Gregorian and Julian calendars.
>   That is, dates are computed by extrapolating the current rules
>   indefinitely far backward and forward in time. As a result,
>   GregorianCalendar may be used for all years to generate meaningful and
>   consistent results. **However, dates obtained using GregorianCalendar
>   are historically accurate only from March 1, 4 AD onward, when modern
>   Julian calendar rules were adopted. Before this date, leap year rules
>   were applied irregularly, and before 45 BC the Julian calendar did not
>   even exist.**

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html

If you open up the source of GregorianCalendar, you find another lovely 'Implementation note' that suggests even more craziness at play:

```
 * Likewise, with the Julian calendar, we assume a consistent
 * 4-year leap year rule, even though the historical pattern of
 * leap years is irregular, being every 3 years from 45 BCE
 * through 9 BCE, then every 4 years from 8 CE onwards, with no
 * leap years in-between.  Thus date computations and functions
 * such as isLeapYear() are not intended to be historically
 * accurate.
```

I've written a date-conversion library that I believe implements the conversion between date types in an 'expected' way: https://github.com/beirtipol/date-converters . I'd hoped to be able to provide a consistent conversion between java.util and java.time dates pre 1582 (Julian->Gregorian shift) but it's not complete.

To answer part of your question, I'm not sure there is a robust way of doing this without testing every single date and timezone pre-1582. I'm attempting to do this and will post back if I figure it out, but there's a long road of testing ahead!

Here's some more information on the joy of Roman-Julian-Gregorian shifts: https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/julian-calendar.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be caused by your input parameter to convert function. The "At -62135769600 seconds" shows that your input value exceeds the singed long limits. Below is a test output for input value representing a timestamp from year one (370 * 24 * 60 * 60).

```
At 31968000 seconds
Timestamp: 1971-01-06 01:00:00.0
Instant:   1971-01-06T00:00:00Z
at Zone:   1971-01-06T01:00+01:00[Europe/Berlin]
LocalDate: 1971-01-06
```

Comment: Nope, `Long.MIN_VALUE == -9223372036854775808L`, while my timestamp is `-62135769600L * 1000L == -62135769600000L` which is well in range.

Comment: I misunderstood the question (year 1 part), sorry.